# where to find "template" interfaces?

Tags: php

i wonder where one can find template interfaces.

eg. i am creating these classes that implements iLog:

```
 DatabaseLog
 ScreenLog
 FileLog
```

i wonder what methods should a typical Log class have?

is there a set of interfaces you could just implement/learn from rather than reinvent the wheel and have to think about the method names.

eg. Interfaces:

```
 iLog
 iDatabase
 iErrorMessage
 etc.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP defines the following interfaces (*should, but may not be complete*):

- Traversable  — The Traversable interface
- Iterator — The Iterator interface
- IteratorAggregate — The IteratorAggregate interface
- ArrayAccess — The ArrayAccess interface
- Serializable — The Serializable interface
- Countable — The Countable interface
- OuterIterator — The OuterIterator interface
- RecursiveIterator — The RecursiveIterator interface
- SeekableIterator — The SeekableIterator interface
- SplObserver  — The SplObserver interface
- SplSubject — The SplSubject interface

See

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php
- http://de.php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php
- http://de.php.net/manual/en/spl.misc.php

As for your Logger Interface, I'd say it should have a method `log($message, level)` and nothing else.

Comment: thanks for the links! regarding the logger interface. shouldnt there be a method called read() ? or is it another interface that is responsible for reading?

Comment: @fayer depends on the what your Log is supposed to do. I was assuming you are talking about a LogWriter. If your Log can read and write, why not separate these concerns into two interfaces and then have your Logger implement LogWriter and LogReader and give one a method write() and the other a method read().

Comment: that was actually a nice separation. i will think about wether to separate them or having them in one interface, although it sounds like each logger should have the ability to read too.

Comment: @fayer a common approach is to have the Logger be a composite that aggregates multiple Writers, so you can write to (for instance) file and db at the same time. The Logger class is then just a Gateway. You could add reading, but the Logger Gateway would then have to know from which Reader, which I find less useful, because it makes you having to know what Reader is there.